# Suppose $0\to A\to B\to C\to D\to 0$ is exact. Let $0\to A[2]\to B[2]\to C[2]\to X\to 0$ be an exact sequence. Then, $X [2]$ is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, derived-functors

Let $A,B,C,D$ be abelian groups and $A$ is **finite**.
**Suppose $D[2]$ is finite.**

Is the following true ?

> Suppose $0\to A\to B\to C\to D\to 0$ is exact.  Let  $0\to A[2]\to 
>  B[2]\to C[2]\to X\to 0$ be an exact sequence(Every morphism of this sequence is restriction of the first exact sequence).
> Then group structure of $X$ is uniquely determined.
> **I want to prove $X [2]$ is finite.**

$A[2]=Hom(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z},A)$, so we want to apply **Ext functor** to a short exact sequence, but our sequence is five term. So I'm at a loss.

I tried to apply Ext functor to $0\to B/A \to C \to D \to 0$, then there is an exact sequence $0 \to (B/Z)[2]\to C[2] \to D[2] \to Ext^1(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z},B/Z)$. If $Ext^1(\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z},B/Z)$ is finite, we are done, but there is no reason unless we give more information about $B/A$.

Comment: Isn't that clear ? $A[2]$ is just the subgroup of elements of $A$ killed by $2$, and same for the others. So $X$ is just the image of the $ C[2]\to D[2]$ induced by $C\to D$ , and is finite.  Or am i misunderstanding something ?

Comment: @GreginGre $X$ is not the image but cockerel. There is no need there is injective map from $X$ to $D$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit ugly but works anyway.

Consider the following diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
@.B[2] @>>> C[2] @>>> X @>>> 0\\
@. @V{f}VV      @V{g}VV      @V{h}VV   \\
0    @>>>B/A     @>>> C @>>> D 
\end{CD}

We know the image of $h$ lands on $D[2]$ which is finite, so to show $X$ is finite, it suffices to show $\ker h$ is finite.

By the snake lemma, there is an exact sequence $$\ker g\rightarrow \ker h\rightarrow \text{coker} f \rightarrow \text{coker}g$$

Note that $\ker g = 0$, so we have $$0\rightarrow \ker h \rightarrow B/(A+B[2])\xrightarrow {\bar{\rho}} C/C[2]$$
where $\rho:B\rightarrow C$ and $\bar \rho$ is the induced map. And we may identify $\ker h$ and $\ker{\bar{\rho}}$.

$x+A+B[2]\in \ker h$ is equivalen to $\bar{\rho}(x+A+B[2])=0$, then to $$\rho(x+A+B[2])\in C[2]\Leftrightarrow 2\rho(x+A+B[2])=0\Leftrightarrow \rho(2x+2A+2B[2])=0$$

finally to

$$\rho(2x+2A)=0\Leftrightarrow 2x\in A$$

Now if $|\ker h|>|A|$, then there are distinct $x+A+B[2], y+A+B[2]$ from $\ker h$, such that $2x=2y$, therefore $x-y \in B[2]$, which contradicts $x-y\not\in A+B[2]$.

---

Actually, there is a straightforward diagram chasing on:

\begin{CD}
0 @>>> A[2] @>>> B[2] @>>> C[2] @>{x'\mapsto x}>> X @>>> 0\\
@.     @VVV      @VVV      @VVV   @V{x\mapsto 0}VV\\
0 @>>> A     @>>{x'''\mapsto 2x''}> B @>{x''\mapsto x'}>{2x''\mapsto 0}> C @>{x'\mapsto 0}>> D @>>> 0 
\end{CD}

Starting with $x\in \ker(X\rightarrow D)$, we can find $x', x''$ as shown above. If $B[2]\rightarrow B$ is surjective, we would be able to show $x=0$, and we're done (the classical [four lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_lemma), used in the proof of the five lemma), but it's not the case. However, note that as $x'\in C[2]$, $2x'=0$, therefore $2x''\in B\mapsto 0\in C$, hence we can further chase to find $x'''\in A$ such that $x'''\mapsto 2x''\in B$. As the lift from $B$ to $A$ (if exists) is unique, we may identify $x'''=2x''$.

Now we show the map $x\mapsto 2x''$ is well-defined and injective. Indeed if $x$ can be lifted to both $x''$ and $y''$ in B, then $x''-y''$ is mapped to $0$ in $X$, hence $x''-y''$ can be lifted to $B[2]$, that is $2x''=2y''$. If $x$ is lifted to $x''$, and $y$ to $y''$, such that $2x''=2y''$, then $x''-y''\in B[2]$, therefore $x=y$ following the first row.

---

(I first posted the following wrong example where $A$ is not finite.)

Let $B=(\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z)^\infty, C=2B\simeq(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^\infty$, where the map $\rho:B\rightarrow C$ is given by the surjective map $\rho(x)=2x$.

Now we can work out that $A\simeq \ker(\rho)=C, D\simeq\text{coker}(\rho)=0$.

And, $A[2]=A, B[2]=A, C[2] = C = A, D[2]=0$. That is, $$0\rightarrow A\xrightarrow{id}A \xrightarrow{0} A\rightarrow X\rightarrow 0$$

Therefore $X\simeq A$ which is not finite.

Comment: In my question, $A$ is assumed to be finite.

Comment: Thank you very much. (＋1)Excellent answer ! In your straightforward diagram chasing way, it seems you managed to embed $X$ into $A$ without assumption $X[2]$ is finite, but there are counterexamples if $X[2]$ is not finite. Where am I missing ?

Comment: I didn't embed $X$ to $A$, only the kernel of $X\rightarrow D$ to $A$.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. Your proof seems to be free of errors. I initially had doubts about the validity of such a statement , but now I am convinced. Thank you very much.

Comment: If we let $f: B/B[2]\to C/C[2]$, by snake lemma, there is a exact sequence $0\to A/A[2]\to kerf\to X\to Imh \to 0$. So if proposition in my question is right, $kerf$ should be finite. But $kerf$ is determined by information of $B$ and $C$, this seems dubious. For the simplest case $A=0$, it is clear that $X\le \#D[2]$, but even in this case, I have no explanation why $kerf$ is finite. Could you tell me how do you deal with $kerf$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I was wrong. Your map $kerh\to A$ is not well defined in the case $A[2]\neq 0$ and your argument does not work. Lift from $B$ to $A$ is not unique. Take $y \in A[2]$, then $x'''$ and $x'''+y$ both goes to $2x'''$ in $B$.

Comment: We can apply snake lemma to $0\to B[2]\to B \to B/B[2] \to 0$ and $0\to C[2]\to C\to C/C[2]\to 0$ and we gain $0\to A[2]=ker(B[2]\to C[2])\to A=ker(B\to C)\to kerf\to X\to Imh \to 0$.

Comment: On the well-definedness, thank you very much. But again, I doubt the map is well defined. Lift from $C\to B$ is dubious because both $x''+y$ and $x''$ goes to $x'$($y\in B[2]$).

Comment: Overall, the information on the relationship between $B$ and $C$ must in some way affect the finiteness of $X$ (as we can see from the snake lemma), and it is strange that everything is determined solely by $A$.

Comment: yes, but if so then $2(x''+y)=2x''$, so they are the same in $A$

Comment: $\ker f$ is indeed finite. Let $\rho: B\rightarrow C$, then $f(x+B[2])=\rho(x) + C[2]$, so $x+B[2]\in \ker f$ iff $\rho(x)\in C[2]$ iff $2\rho(x)=0$ iff $\rho(2x)=0$ iff $2x\in A$. Now the map $x + B[2]\mapsto 2x$ can be shown to be well-defined and injective. This is similar to the first approach in my answer.

Comment: In the case $2C\neq 0$, $2\rho(x)=0$ in $C$ iff onely if $f(x)=0 $ in $B$ iff only iff $x\in B$ comes from $A$,  thus $\#kerf \le A$ ?

Comment: Is the reason for continuing the discussion without assuming $\rho(x) = 0$ from $2\rho(x) = 0$ because there is a concern about the case where $C$ is 2-torsion? Would it be correct to understand that in the case where $C$ is not 2-torsion, it can be immediately deduced as in the comment above?

Comment: those are not at all what I wrote... $2\rho(x)=0$ doesn't imply $\rho(x)=0$ at all but does imply $2x\in\ker\rho=A$. you don't have to know anything about the $2$-torsion of $C$.

Comment: Ah, that's true. I was completely off. However, given the condition that $2x \in A$, the number of candidates for $x$ is finite because $A$ is finite, and the set $Kerf={x + B[2] \in B/B[2] \mid 2x \in A }$ is finite. Isn't it obvious without having to construct a mapping or use proof by contradiction?

Comment: i wasn't taking the most convenient approach or following the same path as you did, but i am sure it's correct.

Comment: The more I chew on it, the more I find this to be a very interesting problem in homology algebra. Would it be okay to discuss over email, including a self-introduction, why I came up with such a proposition and the circumstances behind it?

Comment: thank you！I will send a mail.